# asp:DropDownList onselectedindexchanged not working in Jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

In my project, I am using Asp.net + jquery Mobile. In that I have two dropdown list, I wanaa change the Second DropDown often First DropDown.

But onselectedindexchanged is not working. Even I check with Breakpoint also. No use?.

My Code is Below...
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="OutLet.aspx.cs" Inherits="MobileApp.OutLet" %>

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.5; user-scalable=no;" />
    <%--Mobile Css & jquery 1.0b3--%>
    <link href="Styles/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" data-ajax="false">
      <%--  <div id="mainheader" class="ui-header-fixed ui-bar-a">      
        </div>--%>
        <div id="Div1" class="ui-content ui-body-a" runat="server">           
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOutlet" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" onselectedindexchanged="ddlOutlet_SelectedIndexChanged" >
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlServedAt" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="btnLogin_Click" />        
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" data-role="button" data-inline="true" 
                onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" Visible="False" />
        </div>
      <%--  <div id="Div2" class="ui-footer-fixed ui-bar-e" runat="server">
            <asp:Button ID="btn" Text = "Home" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text = "Back" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" Text = "Table" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button3" Text = "Pax" runat="server" />
        </div>--%>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And I comment the Script Links,.. Now I got ASP.NET Event is perfectly firing. But It not Compact the Mobile?. So Any suggestions/..

```
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I would suggest updating the jQuery library to 1.6.4 and the jQueryMobile library to 1.0.1

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/download/